# Is it possible for the enqueue styles function to mess up my CSS?

Tags: theme-development

I'm an absolute beginner making my first theme, and I wanted to try using register and enqueue for CSS so I could have a separate stylesheet for one page.

I messed around with the functions and decided it wasn't working, so I decided not to use it. However, after I put all my code back to normal, the CSS wouldn't load at all using the typical `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">` format.

When I inspect element on my site and look for the stylesheet under "sources", the `style.css` file it shows is completely blank. I'm at a loss. Is it possible that the enqueue method screwed up my site?

Comment: No, the enqueue method doesn't edit or modify the style.css method, it just references/loads it.  If the contents of the file were deleted/cleared, it wasn't the enqueueing process.

Comment: if your `style.css` is empty it's because the file is empty, enqueuing does not modify files. Also the `link` tag in your question uses a relative URL which will change for every page

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

Enqueuing or registering a stylesheet does not modify the file. If your files contents are now empty then that has nothing to do with enqueuing or registering it.